# Cannot reset select option list, only in one document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron, semantic-ui

I have searched a lot, but I haven't been able to solve the problem yet;
I added a select list to my existing HTML inside a form, but now I cannot reset it through any method.

My html for form is:

```
<form action="#" id="accnt_form" method="post" class="contact-form" name="acc_form">                            
    <fieldset class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" style="display: none">
        <input type="number" id="Ide" placeholder="ID">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" style="text-transform: uppercase" id="AccntNumF" placeholder="Account Number">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" id="BenNameF" style="text-transform: uppercase" placeholder="Beneficiary Name">
    </fieldset>                       
    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" id="AmntF" style="text-transform: uppercase" placeholder="Amount">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
            <!-- <div style="border:.3px solid rgb(185, 184, 184);"> -->
                    <input class="ui primary button" type="button" value="sdf" onclick="my()">                                            
            <select id="IfCodeFa" name="Ifsc" class="drop ui  search selection dropdown">
                <option disabled selected value> Select IFSC Code </option>                                        
              <option value="0">Male</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
              <option value="sdf">sdfMale</option>
              <option value="dfg">dfg</option>
              <option value="ghMale">ds</option>
              <option value="xcv">xcv</option>
              <option value="dfg">dfg</option>
              <option value="ghMale">ds</option>
              <option value="xcv">xcv</option>
              <option value="dfg">dfg</option>
              <option value="ghMale">ds</option>
              <option value="xcv">xcv</option>
            </select>                                 
        </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" id="MobNumF" style="text-transform: uppercase" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase" id="DepByF" placeholder="Deposited By">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="Date" class="input-sm" id="DateF" >
    </fieldset>    
  <fieldset class="col-md-2" id="sv">
        <input type="button" id="save"  class="button big default" value="Save & Print" onclick="saveF()">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-lg-1" id="upd" style="display: none">
        <input type="button" id="update"  class="button big default" value="Update" onclick="updateF()">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="button" id="clear"  class="button big default" value="Clear" onclick="clearF()" >                                    
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

I have tried resetting the form using jQuery, but the select list remains same; I also tried to use `$('#IfCodeFa').dropdown('clear');`, but I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function

This is not a problem of any missing script links, because I tried the same select list in another blank HTML document, and it is working fine.

Comment: can you tell me which dropdown used? is it jquery or bootstrap method?

Comment: "*Not a problem of any missing script links*" I would argue that it is a case of a resource not being (properly) loaded, otherwise the code might not work but you wouldn't receive the error the reported error. Look at the resources tab of your browser's developer tools and check ensure that the scripts are being loaded, that the jQuery/JavaScript is running after the DOM has been constructed and the plugin that you seem to be using is loaded before you try and use it. Also, please show the ("*[mcve]*") jQuery/JavaScript you're using.

Comment: Using Semantic-ui dropdown. Same dropdown working fine on another blank html. @Jinesh

Comment: can you share me this page url?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('#IfCodeFa').empty();
```

or

```
$('#IfCodeFa option').remove();
```

or

```
$('#IfCodeFa').remove('option');
```

Comment: Sorry, these doesnt work. First two codes make the list empty, that is all options are removed. Third code have no effect...@Gopal

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#IfCodeFa').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
function clearF()
{
 $('.restore.example .ui.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Any one from Bellow option :

> `$('#ddlFruits').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;`
>
> ```
> $('#ddlFruits option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
>
> $("#ddlFruits")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
> ```